# event schedules in maria db

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

The following query has failed:

```
CREATE EVENT `UNUSED` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
STARTS '2016-06-14 11:00:00.000000' ENDS '2016-06-30 01:00:00.000000' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
UPDATE quotation_details SET status='UNUSED' WHERE updatedTime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAYS) ;
```

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS)' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DAYS` to `DAY` like following;)

```
CREATE EVENT `UNUSED` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
STARTS '2016-06-14 11:00:00.000000' ENDS '2016-06-30 01:00:00.000000' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
UPDATE quotation_details SET status='UNUSED' WHERE updatedTime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) ;
```

And see `DATE_SUB` function reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp).