# SCHEDULE in MySQL pr minute

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
    UPDATE OnDuty SET Status = '10-7' WHERE minute(timediff(Date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) < 30;
END;
```

Can't seem to get this to work, in PHPMyAdmin it gives me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

I'm lost.. I'm not used to do Schedules in MariaDB.

Comment: maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803510/event-schedules-in-maria-db

Comment: You are possibly missing delimiters - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Check that event_scheduler is on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112395/how-to-set-global-event-scheduler-on-even-if-mysql-is-restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the script working, but now i seems like it does not update the rows...

```
CREATE EVENT `update_status` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
UPDATE OnDuty SET Status = '10-7' WHERE Date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND Status NOT IN('10-5','10-7','Code 0');
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`.  (or is it `+`?)